Slow Gradle shutdown after testing with Testcontainers, Kotlin, Spring Boot
I have a Kotlin Spring Boot application that integrates with redis, and builds with Gradle. Recently I added some Testcontainer integration tests to make sure everything is working as intended. I expected the integration tests to be slow, but somehow the slowest part of the new tests is after they're done, and Gradle has to shut down. I've made a test task that exclusively runs the Testcontainer tests, and the results are as follows on my local machine:

31s for the tests to start (I guess this is starting the spring boot context, pulling images, starting containers, whatever)
10s to execute all the tests
60s for Gradle to shutdown and complete the process after tests are done executing

I've confirmed that after the tests are done executing, the containers are stopped and removed from my Docker, so it's not like Gradle is waiting on that. It sits idle for 60 seconds for no apparent reason. The logs look like this:
2024-07-24T17:46:15.995+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:15.995+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:15.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:15.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:15.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:15.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.992+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.993+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.993+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.993+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.994+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:25.994+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:27.250+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 42: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.251+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Daemon worker Thread 42: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.251+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 2: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.251+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 2: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.251+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.251+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 3: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 5: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 6: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 7: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.252+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 4: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 8: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 9: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 10: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 10: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] included builds: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 11: acquired lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:27.253+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractTrackedResourceLock] Execution worker Thread 11: released lock on worker lease
2024-07-24T17:46:35.994+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:35.994+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:35.995+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:35.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:35.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:35.996+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.989+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.990+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.990+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.991+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.991+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:45.991+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.991+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.991+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.992+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.992+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.992+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
2024-07-24T17:46:55.992+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.


It kind of repeats in a similar manner after this, but in the above snippet it's idle for 40 seconds. Eventually it releases the daemon address registry lock, apparently, and wraps up testing as expected. This only happens when the Testcontainers are involved. When I run all tests excluding the Testcontainer ones, Gradle takes less than a second to wrap up the process after testing is complete.
If I run all the tests together with a simple gradle test the whole process hangs entirely, and the debug logs show that the JVM runs out of heap space memory at some point, and then Gradle stays stuck in this loop, where logging looks the same as above, always trying to get and release the daemon address registry lock.
For completeness, my Testcontainer tests all look similar to this:
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@Import(RedisContainerConfig::class)
class IntegrationTest {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @Container
        val redisContainer: GenericContainer<*> = GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("redis:7-alpine"))
            .withExposedPorts(6379)

        @DynamicPropertySource
        @JvmStatic
        fun redisProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry) {
            registry.add("redis.host") { redisContainer.host }
            registry.add("redis.port") { redisContainer.firstMappedPort }
        }
    }
    // tests
}

where the RedisContainerConfig just configures a custom RedisConnectionFactory bean using the dynamic properties.
I'm struggling to understand why Testcontainers would cause Gradle to hang like this. What could be the cause of it?
